# How can I bring in grid files from Geographix into ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, export

I have a set of grids of subsurface horizons, created from contours, that I have created in Geographix and am having trouble brining them into ArcGIS. Currently when I try to export the grid Geographix is only showing me the cell boundary and is not importing the grid values. Do you know how to correctly export the grid from Geographix so that it will display in ArcGIS as a grid file?

Comment: Is it [**this software**](http://www.lmkr.com/geographix/) that you are using?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  It sounds like what you brought into ArcGIS was the shapefile containing the displayed grid lines which are just display entities.

What you most likely want to to is to export the grid nodes themselves to an XYZ file, which you can then import into ArcGIS.  This would be accessed by File>>Exports>>Surface>>ASCII XYZ Export, and select the IsoMap layer you wish to export from.  You have the option of exporting the grid nodes, the data points (that were used to grid in GeoGraphix Discovery), the created contours (the nodes inlcuding the z values), faults, or other polygons on the layer sych as clipping polygons.  We also export zmap+ files which are very nice to use if ArcGIS accepts them as import files.  I looked and see some additional tools in Arc for dealing with Zmap+ format, so that may be a good way to go.

Global Mapper can convert between a lot of formats including from zmap+ into a native Arc grid format if you wish to preserve the exact grid that was created by GeoGraphix (and not RE-grid the XYZ's in Arc) or if you can't figure out how to handle zmap+ in ArcGIS.

The actual display entities (e.g. contours, polygons, grid lines etc.) are natively stored as shapefiles, so they can be brought directly into Arc without even "exporting" them from GeoGraphix.  I'm guessing that is what you did with the grid lines.

Additional information can be found at support.lmkr.com as well, if you are a licensed user.

One last comment, you might need to have the right Arc licensing to do the Spatial Data Analysis and create the Arc grids.  That used to be the case back when I was more familiar with the Arc side.